# Sci fi short story where people in the U.S. are turned into vegetables (like carrots)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think it may have been some kind of nuclear accident in China that does it. I vaguely remember something about a cloud moving over to the U.S.and some sort of U.S. military involvement. There was also a couple making out in a car and a little girl turning into a carrot and her rabbit eating her fingers.

Comment: I ***wish*** it was the _Lost in Space_ episode "[The Great Vegetable Rebellion](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0636227/)", but sadly I don't think it is.

Comment: All of my searching brings me back to ["Dark They Were, and Golden-Eyed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_They_Were,_and_Golden-Eyed) by Ray Bradbury . Is there a chance you have this story mixed up with another? Whilst it doesn't match couple making out and girl turning into a carrot it does match the rest in a slightly different way.

Comment: It's possible, as my memory isn't what it once was. I'll read the story you mentioned and get back to you. Thanks!