# Xenolinguist assigned to make first contact with space rabbits who cannot understand counterfactuals

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My memory of this story is very thin indeed. It was in a SF digest or anthology in the mid- to late 90s. Read in New York City, but could have been written anywhere (but from what I remember of the writing style, likely American).

A human xenolinguist or xenoanthropologist gets her big break and is assigned to make first contact with a civilization on a planet. Her ultimate aim is to bring them into the fold of some kind of larger galactic federation of many planets and species (the body which has assigned her to this planet). Assimilating planets and new species is a common but prestigious process in this society.

Her assigned planet is populated by what are effectively anthropomorphic rabbits. Like, completely unapologetically, [giant rabbits](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CallARabbitASmeerp). Her first task is to establish communications with them.

They’re friendly and welcoming (portrayed as gentle though somewhat dim), but she discovers an enormous obstacle to communicating with them. They simply cannot conceive of (and therefore use or understand) counterfactual language.

For example, “if I had been there, I would have stopped the fight” is *completely incomprehensible*. They can’t get their heads around it. This is the device that drives the entire plot.

Eventually she discovers a single individual whose thinking is just different enough to be able to get the lightest handle on counterfactual statements. Using this ability,  this rabbit becomes the savior of her program in some way. I have a vague, potentially unreliable memory of some kind of mirror or portal which served as the commutations back to the higher-ups, being both a prominent element as well as the place she had to bring this idiot-savant rabbit to demonstrate she’d succeeded in her assignment.

The overall tone of the story is humorous, lighthearted, and absurd.

Comment: Your description sounds like this is a short story so I have edited in the relevant tag. If this is not appropriate please remove it. I've also tried to make the title more of a brief summary of the story so it's clearer from the title what this is and removed the tag from the title.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thanks for the tag edit. And I’ll take your cues on title, you know the site a lot better than I do.

Comment: Just here to point out that @TheLethalCarrot is helping track down a story about rabbits.

Comment: @VBartilucci It’s my main purpose on the site. I’ve had [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190758/58193) favourites since it was posted in July.

Comment: One question: How technologically advanced were the giant space rabbits when the galactic federation decided to make contact with them? For instance, did they already have electric lights and radio sets? Or were they back in the pre-gunpowder Medieval period, or even earlier? Or what?

Comment: @Lorendiac As far as I can remember, which isn’t very far, they were a modern culture. Not medieval for sure. Don’t remember any mention of technology, but there might have been some. They had homes, if that memory can be relied on. Why do you ask?

Comment: @DanBron I don't remember reading this story, but I did feel that offering a little more detail about the giant rabbits' civilization, such as tech levels, might help jog someone's memory. Also, I found myself wondering: "If they can't wrap their heads around counterfactual statements, does that mean they don't even know how to use the scientific method by coming up with an imaginative hypothesis that might be false, and then devising experiments to test it to find out if it's true? Which might mean they're still at the Stone Age level, for instance?"

Comment: I spent hours googling the crap out of this and came up with nothing. Sounds like a fascinating story, I'd love to read it. Can you remember any more details like the anthology it was published in?

Comment: @Harabeck Unfortunately, no. This is decades ago now. I’ve put everything I currently remember in the Q, but I will absolutely edit it to add anything else that I can come up with. Thank you for your hours of effort on my behalf! I tried the same before I asked, with similarly nil results :/

Comment: Sheila Finch wrote several short stories collected under the title [*The Guild of Xenolinguists*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1975875.The_Guild_of_Xenolinguists?from_search=true). Their job often involved making first contact with alien species. But I don't remember any rabbits and the tone of those stories was often rather sad.